# Internal LazyIinternalConnection error with Mono

Tags: .net, mysql, frameworks, mono, entity

I have an error with a MySql database console app that *must* run on mono. On microsoft's .NET it is running flawlessly but on Mono 2.11.4 it just won't work.

I have already tried setting most of the "Copy Local" settings of the reference to "true", but to no avail.

At the beginning of the application I immediately get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.TypeExtensions ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL c
ode in System.Data.Metadata.Edm.PrimitiveType:GetEdmPrimitiveTypes (): method body is empty.

  at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.TypeExtensions..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbSetDiscoveryService.GetSets () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbSetDiscoveryService.InitializeSets () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.DiscoverAndInitializeSets () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext (IInternalConnection internalConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel model) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor (System.String nameOrConnectionString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at oldforum2vanille.NewForum.vforumEntities1..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at oldforum2vanille.Program.ConvertDiscissionTopics (Int32 newforumid, System.String forumtitle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at oldforum2vanille.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.TypeExtensions ---> System.In
validProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Data.Metadata.Edm.PrimitiveType:GetEdmPrimitiveTypes (): method body is empty.

  at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.TypeExtensions..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbSetDiscoveryService.GetSets () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbSetDiscoveryService.InitializeSets () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.DiscoverAndInitializeSets () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext (IInternalConnection internalConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel model) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor (System.String nameOrConnectionString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at oldforum2vanille.NewForum.vforumEntities1..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at oldforum2vanille.Program.ConvertDiscissionTopics (Int32 newforumid, System.String forumtitle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at oldforum2vanille.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have already tried a proposed solution at http://alpascual.com/post/2011/05/27/Error-Unable-to-find-the-requested-Net-Framework-Data-Provider-It-may-not-be-installed.aspx (because his error message is roughly equal) so I added these lines to my app.config

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data" />
      <add name="ADO.Net driver for MySQL" invariant="MySql.Data" description="ADO.Net driver for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data.MySqlClient, Version=6.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

After some fiddling with the configuration, the Entity Framework now again uses the MySql because of these lines, but Mono just skips this configuration and gives the above Unhandled Exception again. :(

Any of you have an idea? Am I forgetting something?

Comment: InvalidProgramException => It is a bug in Mono. Please report it. The error message in the post you linked to has nothing to do with this error (at all), as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll report it to the guys at mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not scenario supported by Mono. You are not supposed to run Microsoft implementation specific runtime libraries like System.Data.Entity.dll with Mono.

Entity Framework has been open sourced recently (version 6.0) and it's bundled with the latest Mono version. Mono does not support earlier versions of Entity Framework.